# KairosDB - Buffer size Issue while integrating with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

I have recently started using Cassandra and now trying to work with Kairosdb. I have completed the installation and have made the following changes to *cassandra.yaml* file:

start_rpc: true

rpc_address: localhost

rpc_port: 9160

When I try to start kairodb with the command *kairodb run* the message "KairosDB service started" appears, but then it fails with the following error after a while:

*Reducing write buffer size to 150000.  **You need to increase your cassandra capacity or change the kairosdb.datastore.cassandra.write_buffer_max_size property.**
Error resending data*

I have tried changing the write_buffer_max_size in *kairosdb.properties* and meddling with the buffer size in *Cassandra.yaml* but nothing seems to work. Could anyone please suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to reduce the value to a value of like 10000. 
(The "default" is afaik like 500000)

Another way to investigate in this issue is to tweak the JVM Options. (Since both Cassandra and kairosDB are java processes which are running in a JVM environment.)

Maybe you could tell the values or ranges you played around with. 
Cassandra and KairosDB are memory hungry programs. So if your RAM is limited make sure to inspect this aswell.